# NSTextfield renaming implementation on custom button in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, swift, nstableview, nstextfield, nstablecellview

I have NSTableView and a button in NSTableViewCell. I want to implement the functionality when the user clicks on my NSButton and cell goes to the renaming mode of its NSTextField.

I already set up action outlet for button and know when it's clicked but can't really find any info on how to trigger renaming. The answer might be pretty easy but I can't get to it. Thank you in advance!

P.S. I use Swift but any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer is actually very easy, it's the lack of related information that makes it kinda hard. 
So, in case anybody's looking for the same thing, that's how I implemented this feature(it's actually one-liner):

in your action outlet just call

```
cell.textField?.selectText(self)
```

and the text's gonna get selected. After that just keep implementing it as usual.